# Rules for Task Links in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

I wanted to find a set of rules related to how task links work. As example, Task D (sucessor task) may have 3 predecesssor links into that are FS, SS,FF, and all with various dates. How should Task D move based on these links and when their dates change. From what I can trell, a task will allways move to its latest finish date, but wanted to see a set of rules to validate.
I checked general MS Project Support pages, and they talk about 1 to 1 links, but not multiple

[MS Project Links Behind the Scenes](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/How-Project-schedules-tasks-Behind-the-scenes-df3431ab-8d8a-4047-afc6-a87b547dbac0)
Thnaks
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task D can only begin or end after all 3 dependencies have met the set criteria. 
For example, assume tasks A & D are linked as FS;
Tasks B & D are linked as SS;
Tasks C & D are linked as FF,

Then task D cannot start until A is completed || Task B must start also before D or both can start at thesame time ||  Task C must finish before D finishes or at same time as D.

If tasks A & B meet deadlines satisfactorily & C delays, the project will slip.

There's really no set rules, just common sense actually.

But if D is a milestone then this could be a **critical path**. More resources may be needed to ensure deadlines are met.

Comment: Thanks for the note which helps me understand the link process.

Answer (score 0):

The task will be scheduled at the earliest possible date that complies with all dependencies.

Task dependencies don't dictate a fixed date at which the task must start or finish, but a condition that must be met before the task can start / finish. For example in the link you posted, the Start-to-Finish dependency is described as "The dependent task (B) cannot begin until the task that it depends on (A) is complete." So task B can't start before task A is finished, but it can start later. If there are additional dependencies, task B will wait for a date at which all dependencies are verified before starting.

Comment: Thanks, that helps me understand how I should view the links